# conditional mean / integration

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G}$ and a sub-$\sigma$-algebra  $\mathcal{f}$ 
For any $A \in \mathcal{f}$ holds:

$$\int_A E(E(X|G)|F)dP = \int_A E(X|G) dP$$

Why is this the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $Y=E(X|\mathcal G)$. We are asked to show that $\int_A E(Y|\mathcal F)dP=\int_A Y dP$ for $A \in \mathcal F$.  This follows from the definition.

Comment: I got it. Thank you:)